# String concatenation of compile time constants

Tags: java, string, compile-time-constant

I'm trying to understand the String concatenation process. The below initialized variables (`a`, `b`, `str`) are all compile time constants.

When concatenating the compile time constants and comparing it with the equivalent string literals, it should return `true`, right?

But here it returns `true` for primitive value and `false` for a Wrapper class (Integer) variable.

I've gone through a few other SO posts, but I don't get this.

What's happening here?

```
final int a = 0;
final Integer b = 0;
final String str = ":ZERO";

String str1 = a + str;
String str2 = b + str;

System.out.println(str1 == "0:ZERO"); // true
System.out.println(str2 == "0:ZERO"); // false
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between == and equals() in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-and-equals-in-java). Read all posts.

Comment: I wonder if [Compile-time constants and variables](//stackoverflow.com/q/9082971) is a suitable dupe. It says what are valid compile time constant  types and wrapper aren't one. So it should answer the question.

Comment: @DevilsHnd I get the difference b/w == and .equals(), but in the above code, Integer b is a compile time constant, so the value of b could be inferred at compile time itself right.?

Comment: I just wanted to add a nice answer, why did you delete your question?

Comment: @Siva No, `Integer b` is not a compile time constant. See my link.

Comment: @Jens This is not a dupe of == vs `.equals`, should be changed to the link Tom sent as this question is about compile-time constants.

Comment: the compiler does not know how the `Integer` class converts its content to string, neither that it is immutable; so `Integer`, or better, the result from calling its `toString`  cannot be handled as a constant (at least not yet...)

Comment: also note that  `final Integer b = 0;`  is (much probably) being compiled as `final Integer b = Integer.valueOf(0);` which cannot be considered a compile time constant (the result of a method call)

Comment: @user16320675 That explains why `Integer b` is not a compile time constant, Thanks!

Comment: but also note that even if `b` was considered a compile time constant, doing `b + str` involves calling `b.toString()`, which also cannot be considered a compile time constant - the result cannot be *calculated* by the compiler.